# Jquery On keyup function current character get

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to current keyup pressed value  :

like my example: here alert in value="wj" and i want to j value it means current value pressed in input value get

```
alert("wj");
```

i want to get **j** 
[image]

Comment: please explain your question i didnt get it

Comment: i have explain deeply in question

Comment: `alert("j")` - I don‘t get your question either. Give us some more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```js
$('#txt').bind('keyup', function (event) {
 //console.log(event.key);
 var SecondVal=$(this).val().charAt(1)
  if(SecondVal.trim()!=''){
   alert(SecondVal)
   console.log(SecondVal);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt">
```

Comment: i want to get this value in variable how?

Comment: yes but my console in event is not defined error showing

Comment: @RakeshDonga : Are you include the jquery file ???

Comment: yes i have allready included jquery

Comment: @RakeshDonga : Updated my answer please check. replace function (e)  with function (event)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190547/discussion-between-rakesh-donga-and-jijomon-k-a).

Answer (score 0):

```
var secletterval;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#address_field").keyup(event => {
    secletterval = event.key;
     alert(secletterval);
  });
});
```

`address_field` is the id of your textbox

Comment: but how can assign in any variable like `var secletterval = jQuery('.custom-first').val()`

Comment: @RakeshDonga  , i have updated my answer . Is it that you only wanna get the second key only , even when the user have enter any text in textbox .

Answer (score 0):

instead of `keyup` event use `input` event. This demo takes the text of a `contenteditable` `<fieldset>` and splits the text into an array of characters and uses `.pop()` to extract the last character.

### Demo

```js
$('.editor').on('input', edit);

function edit(e) {
  var tgt = $(e.target);
  var key = tgt.next('.key');
  var txt = tgt.text();
  key.text(txt.split('').pop()); 
}
```

```css
:root {font: 400 16px/1 Consolas}
.editor {
  min-height: 100px;
  font: inherit;
}
.key {
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class='editor' contenteditable></fieldset>
<output class='key'></output>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```